# printf("\n") altera o resultado de um inteiro

Tags: c++

Estou a trabalhar num código recursivo que vai incrementando uma variavel cada vez que encontra uma solução para o meu problema (acho que não é relevante nem necessario explicar o problema em questão).

Ora bem, o output do meu programa é suposto imprimir esse contador com o numero de soluções.

Já consegui fazer com que dê a resposta certa. No entanto ao retirar os printf que tinha para fazer debug, apercebi-me que se os retirasse a todos, o resultado final passava a ser 0. Após mais um pouco de pesquisa apercebi-me que tenho que ter `printf("\n\n");` na função recursiva para que seja impresso o output esperado.

Alguma razão assim mais geral?

EDIT:

já descobri o que estava a dar o erro. há uma parte onde estou a declarar um array `int rectLOCAL[8];`  mas não o inicializo a 0 como era suposto ter feito, por isso estava com problemas na comparação do ciclo seguinte.
Ao meter `memset(rectLOCAL,0,8*sizeof(int));` já faz com que o codigo funcione como esperado.

Segue o código:

```
/*  

   _____ ____            _____ _____
  |     |    |              |     |     |   
  |  1  |    |              |  1  |  2  |
  |     |    |          |_____|_____|
   -----   3 |          |     3     |
  |     |    |          |___________|
  |  2  |    |    
  |_____|____|

                                ___________
   ____ _____                  |     3     |
  |    |     |             |_____ _____|
  |    |  1  |             |     |     |    
  |    |     |             |  1  |  2  |
  | 3   -----                  |_____|_____|
  |    |     |    
  |    |  2  |        
  |____|_____|


*/

/*
Description
Fitting rectangles is a game where the player is given a set of small rectangles and needs to create a large
rectangle, using all small rectangles exactly once.
For example, if the player is given the following 3 small rectangles: 1,2,3 seen above
A few possible ways to make a large rectangle would be: the 4 combinations above 

Your task is to find out how many distinct configurations there are to create a large rectangle given the list
of small rectangles.


DISTINCT* por exemplo se o rectangulo 1 e 2 estiverem trocados não conta como +1 solução. 


Two configurations are not distinct if, by removing the indices of the small rectangles, we are not able to
visually distinguish them; this is the case for configurations A and D.
Note that you can rotate rectangles, as can be seen in configuration C


Input
Each test case starts with a line with an integer 1 ≤ n ≤ 8, the number of small rectangles.
The following n lines contain two integers each, w i and h i , the width and height of the ith rectangle
respectively, 1 ≤ i ≤ n .


Output
For each test case, print the number of distinct configurations, it is guaranteed that no more than 10000
solutions exist.

Example
Example input:

3
40 120
50 60
50 60

Example output:
4

*/




#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


/*
rectSizes[][0] -- x
rectSizes[][1] -- y
rectSizes[][2] -- se esta ocupado
*/

int rectSizes[8][3];
int referenceP[9][2];

int nRect;
int rect;

int areaMax;
int teste;
int flagRepetidos;
int placeRect(int mode, int x, int y, int rect, int refPoints[9][2],int RefPoints, int xMax, int yMax);

/*coloca os rectangulos

x,y é o ponto a apagar
rect é o rectangulo a ser ocupado

refPoints atualiza a cada chamada de recursão


o numero max de pontos de ref é nrect+1

*/








int allOcupied(){
    int i;  
    for (i = 0; i<nRect; i++){
        if (rectSizes[i][2]==0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/*verifica se os rectangulos ja foram todos usados*/
int checkRP(int refPoints[9][2]){
    int i;
    int counter=0;
    /*printf("A verificar PR:\n");*/
    for(i=0; i<9;i++){
        if(refPoints[i][0]!=0 || refPoints[i][1]!=0){
            counter++;      
        }   
    }
    if (counter==2){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/*devolve o index do ponto de referencia seguinte

    x,y são os pontos do ponto de referencia a passar

    devolve -1 se o ponto de referencia estiver num eixo
*/
int RPdepois(int RP[9][2], int x,int y,int xMax){
    int j;  
    int ponto = -1;
    int minX = xMax;
    for(j=0;j<9;j++){
        if(RP[j][0] == 0 && RP[j][1]==0){break;}
        if(RP[j][0] == x && RP[j][1]==y){continue;}
        if((RP[j][0]-x)>0 && (RP[j][0]-x)<=minX){
            minX = (RP[j][0]-x);
            ponto = j;
        }

    }
    return ponto;       
}

/*devolve o index do ponto ponto de referencia anterior

    x,y são os pontos do ponto de referencia a passar

    devolve -1 se o ponto de referencia estiver num eixo
*/
int RPantes(int RP[9][2], int x, int y,int yMax){
    int j;  
    int ponto = -1;
    int minY = yMax;
    for(j=0;j<9;j++){
        if((RP[j][0] == 0 && RP[j][1]==0)){break;}
        if((RP[j][0] == x && RP[j][1]==y)){continue;}
        if((RP[j][1]-y)>0 && (RP[j][1]-y)<=minY){
            minY = (RP[j][1]-y);
            ponto = j;
        }
    }   
    return ponto;       
}

/*faz update do Ymax e Xmax*/
int updatexMax(int h, int w, int x, int y, int xMax){
    int l = xMax;
    if(l < x+w){
        l = x+w;
    }
    return l;
}
int updateyMax(int h, int w, int x, int y, int yMax){
    int l = yMax;
    if(l < y+h){
        l = y+h;
    }
    return l;
}
int placeRect(int mode, int x, int y, int rect, int refPoints[9][2],int RefPoints, int xMax, int yMax){





        int k = 0;
        int j;  
        int RP[9][2];

        int ymaxlocal = yMax;
        int xmaxlocal = xMax;
        int temp;

        if(mode == 1){
            temp = rectSizes[rect][0];
            rectSizes[rect][0] = rectSizes[rect][1];
            rectSizes[rect][1] = temp;
        }

        memcpy(RP, refPoints,18*sizeof(int));


        rectSizes[rect][2] = 1;



        /*actualiza os maximos X ou Y caso seja necessario*/
        xmaxlocal = updatexMax(rectSizes[rect][1], rectSizes[rect][0], x, y, xmaxlocal);
        ymaxlocal = updateyMax(rectSizes[rect][1], rectSizes[rect][0], x, y, ymaxlocal);

        /* Caso a area com os x,y maximos ultrapasse a area maxima possivel para os rectangulos dados, volta de imediato atras*/
        if (areaMax<xmaxlocal*ymaxlocal){
            rectSizes[rect][2] = 0;

            if(mode == 1){
                temp = rectSizes[rect][0];
                rectSizes[rect][0] = rectSizes[rect][1];
                rectSizes[rect][1] = temp;
            }
            return 0;
        }


        if(RP[0][0] == 0 && RP[0][1] == 0){
            RP[0][0] = rectSizes[rect][0];
            RP[1][1] = rectSizes[rect][1];
            RefPoints++;
        }
        else{
            while((RP[k][1] != 0) || (RP[k][0] != 0)){

                if(RP[k][1] == y && RP[k][0] == x){
                    int index1 = RPantes(RP, x, y, ymaxlocal);
                    int index2 = RPdepois(RP, x, y, xmaxlocal);
                    int height = rectSizes[rect][1];
                    int width = rectSizes[rect][0];

                    /*remove ponto de ref e adiciona dois*/
                    if(RP[k][1] == 0){  
                        if ((RP[k][1]+height) == RP[index1][1]){
                            RP[k][0] += width;
                        }
                        else{
                            RP[RefPoints][0] = RP[k][0]+rectSizes[rect][0];                 
                            RP[RefPoints][1] = RP[k][1];
                            RP[k][1] += rectSizes[rect][1];
                            RefPoints++;                    
                        }
                    }
                    else if(RP[k][0] == 0){
                        if ((RP[k][0]+width) == RP[index2][0]){
                            RP[k][1] += height;
                        }
                        else{
                            RP[RefPoints][0] = RP[k][0];                    
                            RP[RefPoints][1] = rectSizes[rect][1]+RP[k][1];                     
                            RP[k][0] += rectSizes[rect][0];
                            RefPoints++;
                        }
                    }
                    else{   
                        if(((RP[k][0]+width) == RP[index2][0]) && ((RP[k][1]+height) == RP[index1][1])){                        
                            RP[k][1] = 0;
                            RP[k][0] = 0;
                            RefPoints--;
                        }
                        else if ((RP[k][0]+width) == RP[index2][0]){
                            RP[k][1] += height;
                        }

                        else if ((RP[k][1]+height) == RP[index1][1]){
                            RP[k][0] += width;
                        }
                        else{   
                            RP[k][1] += rectSizes[rect][1];
                            RP[RefPoints][1] = RP[k][1];                    
                            RP[RefPoints][0] = RP[k][0]+rectSizes[rect][0];
                            RefPoints++;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
                k++;
            }
        }   


        /*condicao de paragem*/
        if (allOcupied()){

            if(mode == 1){
                temp = rectSizes[rect][0];
                rectSizes[rect][0] = rectSizes[rect][1];
                rectSizes[rect][1] = temp;
            }
            if (areaMax==xmaxlocal*ymaxlocal && checkRP(RP)){
                teste+=1;   
                rectSizes[rect][2] = 0;
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                rectSizes[rect][2] = 0;
                return 0;
            }       
        }

        /* vamos fazer apenas para o caso onde o rectangulo posto é mais pequeno ou igual ou anterior*/


        int rectLOCAL[8];



        /*EDIT*/
        memset(rectLOCAL,0,8*sizeof(int));



        int p;
        int q;
        int flagA;
        int flagB;
        int mode1b;
        int mode1a;
        int flag;
        int o;
        for(j=0;j<nRect;j++){ 
            flag = 0;

            if(rectSizes[j][2] == 1){continue;}






            /*sem este ciclo, o resultado passa a dar mal no entanto não se altera com a presença do \n*/

            for(o=0;o<nRect;o++)
            {
                if(o==j){
                    continue;
                }
                if(rectLOCAL[o]==1){
                    if((rectSizes[o][0] == rectSizes[j][0] && rectSizes[o][1] == rectSizes[j][1]) || (rectSizes[o][0] == rectSizes[j][1] && rectSizes[o][1] == rectSizes[j][0])){
                        flag =1;
                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
            if(flag==1){continue;}




            rectLOCAL[j]=1;

            for(k=0;k<RefPoints;k++){
                flagA = 0;
                flagB = 0;
                mode1b = 0;
                mode1a = 0;

                /*
                    q index do ponto de referencia anterior ao ponto de referencia x,y
                    p index do ponto de referencia seguinte ao ponto de referencia x,y
                */              
                p = RPdepois(RP,RP[k][0],RP[k][1], xmaxlocal);
                q = RPantes(RP,RP[k][0],RP[k][1], ymaxlocal);

                if(p==-1){
                    flagA = 1;
                }
                else {
                    if(RP[k][0]+rectSizes[j][0] <= RP[p][0]){
                        mode1a = 1;
                        flagA = 1;  
                    }
                    if(RP[k][0]+rectSizes[j][1] <= RP[p][0]){
                        mode1b = 1;
                        flagA = 1;  
                    }

                }
                if(q==-1){
                    flagB = 1;
                }
                else{
                    if(RP[k][1]+rectSizes[j][1] <= RP[q][1]){
                        mode1a = 1;
                        flagB = 1;  
                    }
                    if(RP[k][1]+rectSizes[j][0] <= RP[q][1]){
                        mode1b = 1;
                        flagB = 1;  
                    }
                }

                /*verifica se o rectangulo fica mais alto/comprido do que os rectangulos à sua volta
                e caso seja passa o caso à frente*/
                if(flagA==1 && flagB==1){

                    /*caso esteja a ser testado com as coordenadas invertidas*/
                    if(mode == 1){
                        temp = rectSizes[rect][0];
                        rectSizes[rect][0] = rectSizes[rect][1];
                        rectSizes[rect][1] = temp;
                    }

                    /*verifica se é um quadrado*/
                    if(rectSizes[j][0] != rectSizes[j][1]){

                        if(mode1a==1){placeRect(0,RP[k][0],RP[k][1],j,RP,RefPoints,xmaxlocal,ymaxlocal);}

                        if(mode1b==1){placeRect(1,RP[k][0],RP[k][1],j,RP,RefPoints,xmaxlocal,ymaxlocal);}

                    }
                    else{
                        /* se for um quadrado só precisa de executar uma vez*/
                        placeRect(0,RP[k][0],RP[k][1],j,RP,RefPoints,xmaxlocal,ymaxlocal);

                    }
                }   
                if(mode == 1){
                    temp = rectSizes[rect][0];
                    rectSizes[rect][0] = rectSizes[rect][1];
                    rectSizes[rect][1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        if(mode == 1){temp = rectSizes[rect][0];
                    rectSizes[rect][0] = rectSizes[rect][1];
                    rectSizes[rect][1] = temp;}
        rectSizes[rect][2] = 0;
        return 0;


}



int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int rp[9][2];
    int o;

    memcpy(rp, referenceP,18*sizeof(int));

    scanf("%d", &nRect);
    int temp;
    for(i=0; i<nRect;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &rectSizes[i][0],&rectSizes[i][1]);

        if(rectSizes[i][0]<rectSizes[i][1]){
            temp = rectSizes[i][0];
            rectSizes[i][0] = rectSizes[i][1];
            rectSizes[i][1] = temp;
        }


        /*calcular area para saber area maxima*/
        areaMax+=rectSizes[i][0]*rectSizes[i][1];


    }




    for(i=0; i<nRect;i++)
    {   

        for(o=0;o<i;o++){
            if(i==o){continue;}

            if((rectSizes[o][0] == rectSizes[i][0] && rectSizes[o][1] == rectSizes[i][1]) || (rectSizes[o][0] == rectSizes[i][1] && rectSizes[o][1] == rectSizes[i][0]) ){
                flagRepetidos = 1;
            }
        }
        if(flagRepetidos==1){
            flagRepetidos = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if(rectSizes[i][0] == rectSizes[i][1]){;
            placeRect(0,0,0,i,rp,1,0,0);
        }
        else{
            placeRect(0,0,0,i,rp,1,0,0);
            placeRect(1,0,0,i,rp,1,0,0);
        }

    }
    printf("%d\n",teste);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Joaquim, difícil dizer algo sem ver o código. Edita a pergunta colocando o trecho do código que está com problema.

Comment: o problema é que não sei qual é o sitio especifico que esta com problemas, para alem do printf..  se não tiver um printf("\n\n") dentro da funçao recursiva (tem 300 linhas essa função), não devolve o output esperado. o print pode estar em qualquer parte desde que seja executada pelo menos uma vez dentro de cada chamada recursiva.

Comment: Qual o objetivo dessa função recursiva, e que tipo de resultado ela retorna? Você faz outras chamadas à função `printf()` nessa função? Qual o objetivo dessas chamadas à `printf()`? É apenas para debug da função ou faz parte do objetivo dela?

Comment: A função recursiva retorna um inteiro mas que não é crucial, pois não esta a ser guardado para nada. no entanto ao encontrar uma solução para o problema incrementa uma variavel global, sendo esta variavel o output do programa.
os objectivos dos prints é puramente DEBUG. O unico output do programa deve ser um inteiro, e o printf desse inteiro esta na main.

Comment: Tem um exemplo do output esperado, e um exemplo do output errado (ao tirar `printf(\n\n)` da função recursiva)?

Comment: eu ponho ja um link para o ghostbin com o codigo e com explicações de onde esta o problema.

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/hzey5    aqui está. Tentei explicar o melhor que possivel a explicação esta em ingles, espero que não seja problema. O print problematico esta na linha 230

Comment: Dei uma olhada no código e não consegui identificar nada que pudesse causar esse comportamento, não faz o menor sentido, não é? O que acontece ao _debugar_ o código passo a passo, quando você tira o `printf("\n\n)` _ofensivo_?

Comment: ao fazer debug do codigo eu meto prints com \n tornando o printf("\n \n") "useless", porque passam a ser chamados dois \n dentro da função recursiva, pelo o que eu reparei, não interessa onde estão, desde que sejam chamado o \n 2x dentro da função recursiva.

Comment: apos mais um pouco de investigação descobri que se retirar a parte do codigo das linhas 451-465, no link que enviei, o \n para de afectar o resultado final.

Comment: Aconselho a tentar minimizar o código tanto quanto possível retirando todo o código comentado e comentários não relevantes, e coloca-lo na pergunta. De preferência focando e realçando a função com o problema, explicando qual o resultado que ela dá com e sem o `printf`. Sem ser assim não vejo como possa vir a ter uma resposta à sua pergunta. Lembre-se que se deve esforçar o máximo possível para que seja fácil às pessoas que passam na sua pergunta de a responder.

Comment: já editei o codigo no ghostbin, limpei comentarios desnecessarios e tentei fazer com que fosse perceptivel o sitio que me esta a dar problemas

Comment: Joaquim, a situação toda está realmente muito sinistra. Eu rodei o programa usando aquele input de exemplo (3 -> 40 120 -> 50 60 -> 50 60), e, deixando o `printf("\n\n")` dentro da função recursiva, o resultado foi **2**, se eu comento o `printf` o resultado é **3**. Também coloquei um contador na função recursiva e notei que com o `printf` a função recursiva é executada **26 vezes** e sem o `printf` a mesma função é executada **36 vezes**. E, de fato, se o trecho de código entre as linhas _451_ e _465_ é comentado, o resultado passa a ser sempre o mesmo, com ou sem `printf`.

Comment: Mas em nenhum momento o resultado foi **4**, como estava descrito no exemplo. E notei que o `printf` não precisa ser especificamente `printf("\n\n")`, eu coloquei um `printf("count: %d", count)`, para exibir o contador, e também teve o mesmo comportamente do `printf("\n\n")`.

Comment: Que bom que descobriu o problema, Joaquim. Mas, para mim segue o mistério de porque um `printf` alterava o resultado da função. Será que é porque quando o `printf` era chamado, internamente ele copiava valores para a memória, que seria por coincidência o local da memória que seria usado pelo seu array não-inicializado?

Comment: pois, sinceramente tambem não faço ideia. Ao correr o meu programa com o valgrind ele acusava Conditional jumps or moves... era a unica dica que eu tinha